# Recovery of MapInfo transaction files (*.TMA, *.TIN, *.TDA)

Tags: mapinfo, tab

MapInfo (v 12.5.1 - 64 Bit, Release Build 122) just crashed on me while I was in the middle of modifying several tables and adding a few new ones to an existing Workspace.

Unfortunately the changes had not yet been saved, so were still being stored in the transaction files (*.TMA, *.TIN, *.TDA).  When I reopened the workspace, I was not expecting the unsaved changes to be recovered automatically, but I found no method to try to import the existing transaction files (which were still on my hard drive) so I could recover my lost data.

Is there a method built into MapInfo (or not) that can be used to recover this lost data?  Or am I forced to recreate it?

Comment: I believe that it is practically impossible to recover the lost data from the transaction files, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

These transaction files seems in some way bound to the session that created them, so you can't use them from a new session.

Let me add two recommendations:

1. Goto [ideas.pb.com](http://ideas.pb.com) and add a request/idea for Pitney Bowes to add a capability for getting to the data in the transaction files
2. Download and install the latest patch for MapInfo Pro 12.5. You can find the patch here: [Download for MapInfo Pro](http://www.pbinsight.com/support/product-downloads/for/mapinfo-professional)